# Retrieve value from XML response using SSJS in a SSJS Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, xml, ssjs

Use a SSJS Activity I am getting a response in XML from an API call. I need to parse the XML for a specific value. Is this possible in a SSJS Activity?

Comment: I tried using a regex that works client-side but I get this error "Jint.JintException:  Object expected: match".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by using Stringify on the response. Stringify(result.Response).match works.

Comment: Possible to share code? In a similar dilema

Comment: I'm trying to remember what project this is for. I'll do some digging. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The online help does not say so.  But, I believe the script activity will also process **AMPSCript**.

SSJS does a great job at parsing **JSON**.  But, there are no SSJS function for parsing XML.  Consider using the following **AMPScript** functions:  [BuildRowSetFromXML()](http://wiki.memberlandingpages.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions/#BuildRowSetFromXML) & [TransformXML()](http://wiki.memberlandingpages.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions/#TransformXML).

Comment: AMPScript runs in Scripts? Is says "Server Side Java Script". I'll have to give that a try.